# RAID1 vs rsync - security?

Tags: security, rsync, raid

I'm setting up a NAS-Server using an Odroid XU4 and two 2TB HDDs.
Which setup would be more secure (lower risk of losing data / easier recovery):

1. setup a RAID1 with mdadm
2. have two separate devices, sync devices using rsync periodically

I know if one drive crashed in 2. I'd lose the data created/modified since last sync, but when using a RAID it would be a bit more "difficult" to get the data from the "still working" drive.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last sentence. In a RAID 1 array, when you lose a disk, the array would continue to stay online in a _degraded_ state until the failed disk is replaced. You should have no difficulty accessing the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal favourite is:

- create a Raid1 Software Raid (mdadm)
- do regular incremental backups
- do weekly full-backups.

The software raid1 protects you from online-faults, such that the volume is active ALWAYS, as long as one drive is okay. The software raid automatically syncs the contents between the drives, so you always have the up-to-date data present.
It is not difficult to retrieve the data from the drive, since raid1 is a mirror. You need to make sure to replace a failed drive as soon as possible, though.

Backups protect you from ups-i-deleted-an-important-file errors.

Remember: If data is not backed-up, it is not important ...

Comment: Having been burnt more than once I wholeheartedly agree. RAID1 for online fault tolerance *and* regular backups. Whether you chose RAID1 or rsync you'll just have an exact replica of your data but no history to fall back on. In the case of a mistake, a deleted file, or a virus that trashes your data RAID1/rsync do not protect you. Only a regular backup does.

Comment: +1.  Another similar option is to use either `btrfs` or `zfs` instead of RAID-1.  Both of these will give you RAID1-like mirroring, snapshots, error-detection and correction, subvolumes, optional fs/subvolume compression, and (if you have another zfs or btrfs machine somewhere) the ability to use `zfs send` or `btrfs send` instead of `rsync` for backups.  advantage is that `rsync` has to examine each block of each file to know what has changed before it sends it, while btrfs and zfs already know exactly which blocks have changed between snapshots and send only those blocks.

Answer (score 4):

**RAID1** will destroy everything in the case [*you* make a mistake](https://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root) or a virus decides to destroy your files.
But, it makes it easy to fix actual hard drive failures.

**rsync** will cause downtime in the (very common) case that your primary hard drive fails, because you have to transfer the data back (or at least swap out the drives).
But, it makes it easy to recover from software-caused problems.

For "normal" home use, I'd always use rsync or a different backup solution, mostly because you usually don't want to spend money on three hard drives (one of them reachable via the network), all with the same content on it.
For everything else, of course, the correct answer is: both!